# Modify Dynamic Property Selector Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I wrote a small method that can build a property selector lambda from a string - something like what Dynamic LINQ does and a million other examples here on Stack Overflow.

For example, given this `Expressions.PropertySelector<Type, PropertyType>("Source.Date")`, it would return a `Func`, if compiled, similar to this `(Type) => type.Source.Date`.

Anyway I ran into a situation where not only do I need to select the property, but also invoke a method defined by its type.

So for example, I want the equivalent of this: `(Type) => Type.Source.Date.ToString("Y")`. I know I can probably modify my `PropertySelector` method to detect a method call and build the appropriate expression, but I am curious if there is a better way.

For those curious why I need this: Basically its for an Entity Framework backed repository I am building. I have a method that allows the caller to pass a lambda to represent a property to group on. The caller themselves constructs the lambda based on user input. So I figured doing it this way would be the best approach.

But, for example, what if the property to group on is a `DateTime`. And I would to group on its formatted string.

What's the best approach to handle a scenario like this? Ideally, I would like the caller, after the expression is dynamically built, to modify it.

Comment: How exactly would the caller modify it? Do you know the name of the method only as a string? Or is it known at compile time?

Comment: @svick I know the name of the method at compile time. But I am also curious how it can be done if I have it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have two expressions: one from `T1` to `T2`, the second from `T2` to `T3` and you want to combine them into one (from `T1` to `T3`). You can use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to do this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, T3>> CombineExpressions<T1, T2, T3>(
    Expression<Func<T1, T2>> first, Expression<Func<T2, T3>> second)
{
    Expression<Func<T1, T3>> result = x => second.Invoke(first.Invoke(x));
    // I think double Expand here is necessary because of Invoke inside Invoke
    return result.Expand().Expand();
}
```

For example:

```
Expression<Func<Person, DateTime>> getDateExpression =
    person => person.DOB;
Expression<Func<DateTime, string>> dateFormatExpression =
    date => date.ToString("Y");
Expression<Func<Person, string>> result =
    CombineExpressions(getDateExpression, dateFormatExpression);
```

Here, `result` contains the expression `(Person x) => x.DOB.ToString("Y")`.

You can build one or both of the expressions dynamically, it won't change how the combining works.

Comment: You my friend are a genius! Your example worked great, though I had to change this line, `Expression<Func<T1, T3>> result = x => second.Invoke(first.Invoke(x))`, to `Expression<Func<T1, T3>> result = x => second.Compile().Invoke(first.Compile().Invoke(x))`, in the `CombineExpressions` method. I also did not need the extra call to `result.Expand().Expand();`. It worked fine without it. If you can update your answer, I'll mark this answer as correct. Also, if you have the time, can you explain the benefits of the `Expand()` call. I actually did not need to reference LINQKit at all.

Comment: @agarhy If you really are using Entity Framework, then I'm quite sure your code won't work properly. If you use `Compile()`, you don't have `Expression` anymore, you have just a `Func`. And EF can't build SQL out of that.

Comment: It works, though I believe it is applied in memory after EF pulls the data set since it can't translate the `Func` to an expression like you mentioned. The reason I call `Compile()` though is because I think `Invoke` is a static method for an `Expression`. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @agarhy If you're okay with executing in memory, then you're not doing it wrong, just unnecessarily complicated (you don't need `Expression`s, you can use `Func`s directly). But if you want to execute it as SQL (which I assumed was the goal) then you would need the `Invoke()` and `Expand()` extension methods from LINQKit.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Ideally, I would like to execute as SQL like you mentioned. But now, when I use LINQKit like in your example, I get this error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method`. Looks like it is having trouble translating the date to string conversion.

Comment: @agarhy Yeah, looks like `ToString()` is not supported.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. No worries, as long as I now understand the basics of how it can be done, I can build on it. Thanks so much for your incredible patience and help. If I can up-vote more than once I would.